# Html to Word Export using PHP Headers

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, export, docx

I converted html and php pages to word with php headers, Now I want to add header image and footer for each every page of word documents with PHP headers.Please provide me a solution using PHP headers.

Below is the code i'am using for converting html to word.

```
$html ='Hello World";
$filename = 'mydoc';
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.msword");
header("Expires: 0");//no-cache
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");//no-cache
header("content-disposition: attachment;filename=".$filename.".doc");
echo "<html>";
echo $html;
echo "</html>";
```

Comment: SO isn't a place where people will just do the work for you.  Can you please provide examples that you've tried already so that members can then advise / assist.  Just saying "Please provide me a solution using PHP headers" is not how to ask a question

Comment: When you say you want to add header and footer for every page of the word document, are you meaning the header and footer that can be set in Word itself?  Without an interop of some sure that would be possible

Comment: I want to add header and footer while exporting from html to word dynamically, Not in word manually.My html code is dynamic, it will come multiple pages while exporting to word.